# Retrieve data from eBird API and create multi-level hierarchy of locations

Tags: vba, excel, api

As you may know, I [like birds](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/187418/75587). The Cornell Lab of Ornithology has a tool called [eBird](https://ebird.org/home) where you can submit records of the birds you identified. I recently learned they have an [API](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/664302/ebird-api-20/2HTbHW) that I can query, yay! Before this I was just hitting pages and parsing source code.

I've never really queried an API before.

***Oh and I normally use late binding, but for this you need these (additional) references***

- Microsoft HTML Object Library
- Microsoft Internet Controls
- Microsoft WinHTTP Services, version 5.1
- Microsoft Scripting Runtime

---

### Code

I have two modules - one to get the data from the API and one to create a hierarchy of that data. I used my [Comb Sort Multi-dimensional Array on Key](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/155640/75587) *(which can be reviewed there instead of here, if need be*).

#### Module PopulateLocations.bas

```
Option Explicit

Const DELIMITER As String = "},{"

'| */ Documentation for Regions
'| For this API regionType can be subnational2, subnational1, or country (ISO3166)
'| I will refer to subnational1 as majorRegion and subnational2 as minorRegion /*

Public Sub PopulateEbirdRegions()
    Const minorRegionBaseURL As String = "https://ebird.org/ws2.0/ref/region/list/subnational2/"
    Const majorRegionBaseURL As String = "https://ebird.org/ws2.0/ref/region/list/subnational1/"
    Dim countryArray As Variant
    Dim majorArray As Variant
    Dim minorArray As Variant
    countryArray = RetrieveCountries
    majorArray = GetRegions(majorRegionBaseURL, countryArray, MajorSheet)
    minorArray = GetRegions(minorRegionBaseURL, majorArray, MinorSheet, True)
    
    CreateHierarchy.CreateHierarchy countryArray, majorArray, minorArray
End Sub

Private Function RetrieveCountries() As Variant
    Const COUNTRY_URL As String = "https://ebird.org/ws2.0/ref/region/list/country/world?fmt=csv"
    Dim responseText As String
    Dim response As Variant
    
    responseText = SendHttpRequest(COUNTRY_URL)
    response = Split(responseText, DELIMITER)
    
    Dim countryArray() As String
    ReDim countryArray(LBound(response) To UBound(response), 1 To 2)
    Dim index As Long
    For index = LBound(response) To UBound(response)
        countryArray(index, 1) = ExtractCode(response(index))
        countryArray(index, 2) = ExtractName(response(index))
    Next
    
    countryArray(UBound(countryArray), 2) = Left$(countryArray(UBound(countryArray), 2), Len(countryArray(UBound(countryArray), 2)) - 2)
    
    WriteToSheet countryArray, countrySheet, "Country Code", "Country"
    RetrieveCountries = countryArray
End Function

Private Function GetRegions(ByVal baseRegionURL As String, ByVal sourceArray As Variant, ByVal targetSheet As Worksheet, Optional ByVal isMinor As Boolean = False) As Variant
    Dim fileType As String
    fileType = ".json"

    Dim subNationalValue As String
    Dim responseText As String
    Dim targetURL As String
    Dim index As Long
    index = 1
    Dim resultIndex As Long
    resultIndex = index

    Dim resultArray() As String
    ReDim resultArray(LBound(sourceArray) To UBound(sourceArray), 1 To 2)

    For index = LBound(sourceArray) To UBound(sourceArray)
        subNationalValue = sourceArray(index, 1)
        targetURL = baseRegionURL & subNationalValue & fileType
        responseText = SendHttpRequest(targetURL)
        
        If isMinor Then
            If Not responseText = "[]" Then
                resultArray(resultIndex, 1) = subNationalValue
                resultArray(resultIndex, 2) = responseText
                resultIndex = resultIndex + 1
            End If
        Else
            resultArray(index, 1) = sourceArray(index, 1)
            resultArray(index, 2) = responseText
        End If
    Next
    
    GetRegions = CleanSource(resultArray, targetSheet)
End Function


Private Function CleanSource(ByVal sourceArray As Variant, ByVal targetSheet As Worksheet) As Variant
    Const FIRST_HEADER As String = "Region Code"
    Const SECOND_HEADER As String = "Region Name"
    Dim cleanIndex As Long
    cleanIndex = 1
    Dim index As Long
    Dim sourceIndex As Long
    Dim response As Variant
    Dim cleanArray() As String
    ReDim cleanArray(1 To 10000, 1 To 2) 'I would like to not hard-code this, but it's not variable in itself, but variable across queries

    For sourceIndex = LBound(sourceArray) To UBound(sourceArray)
        If sourceArray(sourceIndex, 2) <> "[]" Then
            response = Split(sourceArray(sourceIndex, 2), DELIMITER)
            For index = LBound(response) To UBound(response)
                cleanArray(cleanIndex, 1) = ExtractCode(response(index))
                cleanArray(cleanIndex, 2) = ExtractName(response(index))
                cleanIndex = cleanIndex + 1
            Next
        End If
    Next
    
    Dim returnArray() As String
    ReDim returnArray(1 To cleanIndex - 1, 1 To 2)
    For index = 1 To UBound(returnArray)
        returnArray(index, 1) = cleanArray(index, 1)
        returnArray(index, 2) = cleanArray(index, 2)
    Next

    WriteToSheet returnArray, targetSheet, FIRST_HEADER, SECOND_HEADER
    CleanSource = returnArray
End Function

Private Function SendHttpRequest(ByVal targetURL As String) As String
    Const API_KEY As String = ""
    Const API_REQUEST_HEADER As String = "X-eBirdApiToken"
    Dim httpRequest As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    Set httpRequest = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    httpRequest.Open "GET", targetURL
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader API_REQUEST_HEADER, API_KEY
    httpRequest.send
    SendHttpRequest = httpRequest.responseText
End Function

Private Function ExtractCode(ByVal targetString As String) As String
    ExtractCode = Mid$(targetString, InStr(1, targetString, "code") + 7, InStr((InStr(1, targetString, "code") + 7), targetString, ",") - InStr(1, targetString, "code") - 8)
End Function

Private Function ExtractName(ByVal targetString As String) As String
    ExtractName = Mid$(targetString, InStrRev(targetString, ":") + 2, Len(targetString) - InStrRev(targetString, ":") - 2)
End Function

Private Sub WriteToSheet(ByVal valueArray As Variant, ByVal targetSheet As Worksheet, ByVal firstHeader As String, ByVal secondHeader As String)
    Const FIND_STRING As String = "}"
    targetSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = firstHeader
    targetSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = secondHeader
    CombSortArray valueArray, 2
    Dim printRange As Range
    Set printRange = targetSheet.Range(targetSheet.Cells(2, 1), targetSheet.Cells(UBound(valueArray) + 2, 2))
    printRange.Value = valueArray
    printRange.Replace What:=Chr$(34) & FIND_STRING, Replacement:=vbNullString

End Sub

Private Sub CombSortArray(ByRef dataArray As Variant, Optional ByVal numberOfColumns As Long = 1, Optional ByVal sortKeyColumn As Long = 1, Optional ByVal sortAscending As Boolean = True)
    'https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/155640/comb-sort-multi-dimensional-array-on-key
    Const SHRINK As Double = 1.3
    Dim initialSize As Long
    initialSize = UBound(dataArray, 1)
    Dim gap As Long
    gap = initialSize
    Dim index As Long
    Dim isSorted As Boolean

    Do While gap > 1 And Not isSorted
        gap = Int(gap / SHRINK)
        If gap > 1 Then
            isSorted = False
        Else
            gap = 1
            isSorted = True
        End If
        index = 1
        Do While index + gap <= initialSize
            If sortAscending Then
                If dataArray(index, sortKeyColumn) > dataArray(index + gap, sortKeyColumn) Then
                    SwapElements dataArray, numberOfColumns, index, index + gap
                    isSorted = False
                End If
            Else
                If dataArray(index, sortKeyColumn) < dataArray(index + gap, sortKeyColumn) Then
                    SwapElements dataArray, numberOfColumns, index, index + gap
                    isSorted = False
                End If
            End If
            index = index + 1
        Loop
    Loop

End Sub
Private Sub SwapElements(ByRef dataArray As Variant, ByVal numberOfColumns As Long, ByVal i As Long, ByVal j As Long)
    Dim temporaryHolder As Variant
    Dim index As Long
    For index = 1 To numberOfColumns
        temporaryHolder = dataArray(i, index)
        dataArray(i, index) = dataArray(j, index)
        dataArray(j, index) = temporaryHolder
    Next
End Sub
```

Then this module passes the arrays to

#### Module CreateHierarchy.bas

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub CreateHierarchy(ByVal countries As Variant, ByVal majorRegions As Variant, ByVal minorRegions As Variant)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim countryIndex As Long
    Dim majorIndex As Long
    Dim minorIndex As Long
    Dim currentRow As Long
    currentRow = 2
    Dim country As String
    Dim region As String
    Dim subRegion As String
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Set targetSheet = HierarchyTest
    
    minorIndex = 2
    majorIndex = 2

    For countryIndex = LBound(countries) + 1 To UBound(countries)
        If Not IsEmpty(targetSheet.Cells(currentRow, 1)) _
        Or Not IsEmpty(targetSheet.Cells(currentRow, 3)) _
        Or Not IsEmpty(targetSheet.Cells(currentRow, 5)) Then
            currentRow = currentRow + 1
        End If
        
        country = countries(countryIndex, 1)
        targetSheet.Cells(currentRow, 1).Value = country
        targetSheet.Cells(currentRow, 2).Value = countries(countryIndex, 2)
        For majorIndex = majorIndex To UBound(majorRegions)
            region = Left$(majorRegions(majorIndex, 1), 2)

            If StrComp(country, region, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                region = majorRegions(majorIndex, 1)
                targetSheet.Cells(currentRow, 3).Value = region
                targetSheet.Cells(currentRow, 4).Value = majorRegions(majorIndex, 2)
                
                For minorIndex = minorIndex To UBound(minorRegions)
                    subRegion = Left$(minorRegions(minorIndex, 1), Len(region))
                    If StrComp(region, subRegion, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                        targetSheet.Cells(currentRow, 5).Value = minorRegions(minorIndex, 1)
                        targetSheet.Cells(currentRow, 6).Value = minorRegions(minorIndex, 2)
                        currentRow = currentRow + 1
                    ElseIf StrComp(region, subRegion, vbTextCompare) = -1 Then
                        GoTo skip
                    End If
                Next
            currentRow = currentRow + 1
            ElseIf StrComp(country, region, vbTextCompare) = -1 Then
                GoTo jump
            End If
skip:
        currentRow = currentRow + 1
        Next
jump:

    Next

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I'm not at all happy with this hierarchy procedure, but it does its job. I'm sure there's a more clever way to do it, but I'm embarrassed about how long it took me to write *this* junk. If you point out I have three `for` loops with two `if`s in them and make fun of me - I deserve it.

---

### Substitute Code

Because I doubt you have an API key, I've made the [raw data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mPKkkKo_2h7lLyyc9TSlJztLez-mYFla) available and you can alter the Hierarchy module so it doesn't require arguments to execute:

```
Public Sub CreateHierarchy()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim countries As Variant
    Dim majorRegions As Variant
    Dim minorRegions As Variant
    countries = RetrieveData(countrySheet)
    majorRegions = RetrieveData(MajorSheet)
    minorRegions = RetrieveData(MinorSheet)

...

End Sub

Private Function RetrieveData(ByVal targetSheet As Worksheet) As Variant
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Set dataRange = targetSheet.Range(targetSheet.Cells(1, 1), targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, 2))
    RetrieveData = dataRange
End Function
```

---

### Example return text from `SendHTTPRequest`

This is (some of) the raw data I get and parse, in case there's a better way to do that -

**Country**

```
[{"code":"AF","name":"Afghanistan"},{"code":"AL","name":"Albania"},{"code":"DZ","name":"Algeria"},{"code":"AS","name":"American Samoa"},{"code":"AD","name":"Andorra"},{"code":"AO","name":"Angola"},{"code":"AI","name":"Anguilla"},{"code":"AQ","name":"Antarctica"},{"code":"AG","name":"Antigua and Barbuda"},{"code":"AR","name":"Argentina"},{"code":"AM","name":"Armenia"},{"code":"AW","name":"Aruba"},{"code":"AC","name":"Ashmore and Cartier Islands"},{"code":"ZM","name":"Zambia"},{"code":"ZW","name":"Zimbabwe"}]
```

**Major Region**

```
[{"code":"AF-BDS","name":"Badakhshan"},{"code":"AF-BDG","name":"Badghis"},{"code":"AF-BGL","name":"Baghlan"},{"code":"AF-BAL","name":"Balkh"},{"code":"AF-BAM","name":"Bamian"},{"code":"AF-DAY","name":"Daykondi"},{"code":"AF-FRA","name":"Farah"},{"code":"AF-FYB","name":"Faryab"},{"code":"AF-GHA","name":"Ghazni"},{"code":"AF-GHO","name":"Ghowr"},{"code":"AF-HEL","name":"Helmand"},{"code":"AF-HER","name":"Herat"},{"code":"AF-JOW","name":"Jowzjan"},{"code":"AF-KAB","name":"Kabol"},{"code":"AF-KAN","name":"Kandahar"},{"code":"AF-KAP","name":"Kapisa"},{"code":"AF-KHO","name":"Khowst"},{"code":"AF-KNR","name":"Konar"},{"code":"AF-KDZ","name":"Kondoz"},{"code":"AF-LAG","name":"Laghman"},{"code":"AF-LOW","name":"Lowgar"},{"code":"AF-NAN","name":"Nangarhar"},{"code":"AF-NIM","name":"Nimruz"},{"code":"AF-NUR","name":"Nurestan"},{"code":"AF-ORU","name":"Oruzgan"},{"code":"AF-PIA","name":"Paktia"},{"code":"AF-PKA","name":"Paktika"},{"code":"AF-PAN","name":"Panjshir"},{"code":"AF-PAR","name":"Parwan"},{"code":"AF-SAM","name":"Samangan"},{"code":"AF-SAR","name":"Sar-e Pol"},{"code":"AF-TAK","name":"Takhar"},{"code":"AF-WAR","name":"Wardak"},{"code":"AF-ZAB","name":"Zabol"}]
```

**Minor Region**

```
[{"code":"AR-B-AA","name":"Adolfo Alsina"},{"code":"AR-B-AC","name":"Adolfo Gonzales Chaves"},{"code":"AR-B-AL","name":"Alberti"},{"code":"AR-B-AB","name":"Almirante Brown"},{"code":"AR-B-AM","name":"Ameghino"},{"code":"AR-B-BM","name":"Arrecifes"},{"code":"AR-B-AV","name":"Avellaneda"},{"code":"AR-B-AY","name":"Ayacucho"},{"code":"AR-B-AZ","name":"Azul"},{"code":"AR-B-BB","name":"Bahía Blanca"},{"code":"AR-B-BC","name":"Balcarce"},{"code":"AR-B-BD","name":"Baradero"},{"code":"AR-B-BJ","name":"Benito Juárez"},{"code":"AR-B-BZ","name":"Berazategui"},{"code":"AR-B-BS","name":"Berisso"},{"code":"AR-B-BO","name":"Bolívar"},{"code":"AR-B-BG","name":"Bragado"},{"code":"AR-B-BR","name":"Brandsen"},{"code":"AR-B-CM","name":"Campana"},{"code":"AR-B-CS","name":"Capitán Sarmiento"},{"code":"AR-B-CC","name":"Carlos Casares"},{"code":"AR-B-CT","name":"Carlos Tejedor"},{"code":"AR-B-CA","name":"Carmen de Areco"},{"code":"AR-B-CI","name":"Castelli"},{"code":"AR-B-CL","name":"Cañuelas"},{"code":"AR-B-CB","name":"Chacabuco"},{"code":"AR-B-CH","name":"Chascomús"},{"code":"AR-B-CV","name":"Chivilcoy"},{"code":"AR-B-CO","name":"Colón"},{"code":"AR-B-CD","name":"Coronel Dorrego"},{"code":"AR-B-CP","name":"Coronel Pringles"},{"code":"AR-B-CE","name":"Coronel Suárez"},{"code":"AR-B-CR","name":"Coronel de Marina Leonardo Rosales"},{"code":"AR-B-DA","name":"Daireaux"},{"code":"AR-B-DO","name":"Dolores"},{"code":"AR-B-EN","name":"Ensenada"},{"code":"AR-B-ES","name":"Escobar"},{"code":"AR-B-EB","name":"Esteban Echeverría"},{"code":"AR-B-EC","name":"Exaltación de la Cruz"},{"code":"AR-B-FC","name":"Florencio Varela"},{"code":"AR-B-GD","name":"General Alvarado"},{"code":"AR-B-GA","name":"General Alvear"},{"code":"AR-B-GE","name":"General Arenales"},{"code":"AR-B-GB","name":"General Belgrano"},{"code":"AR-B-GG","name":"General Guido"},{"code":"AR-B-GJ","name":"General Juan Madariaga"},{"code":"AR-B-GM","name":"General La Madrid"},{"code":"AR-B-GH","name":"General Las Heras"},{"code":"AR-B-GL","name":"General Lavalle"},{"code":"AR-B-GZ","name":"General Paz"},{"code":"AR-B-GI","name":"General Pinto"},{"code":"AR-B-GP","name":"General Pueyrredón"},{"code":"AR-B-GR","name":"General Rodríguez"},{"code":"AR-B-GN","name":"General San Martín"},{"code":"AR-B-GS","name":"General Sarmiento"},{"code":"AR-B-GT","name":"General Viamonte"},{"code":"AR-B-GV","name":"General Villegas"},{"code":"AR-B-GU","name":"Guaminí"},{"code":"AR-B-HY","name":"Hipólito Yrigoyen"},{"code":"AR-B-JU","name":"Junín"},{"code":"AR-B-LC","name":"La Costa"},{"code":"AR-B-LM","name":"La Matanza"},{"code":"AR-B-LT","name":"La Plata"},{"code":"AR-B-LS","name":"Lanús"},{"code":"AR-B-LR","name":"Laprida"},{"code":"AR-B-LF","name":"Las Flores"},{"code":"AR-B-LA","name":"Leandro N. Alem"},{"code":"AR-B-LI","name":"Lincoln"},{"code":"AR-B-LO","name":"Lobería"},{"code":"AR-B-LB","name":"Lobos"},{"code":"AR-B-LZ","name":"Lomas de Zamora"},{"code":"AR-B-LU","name":"Luján"},{"code":"AR-B-ML","name":"Magdalena"},{"code":"AR-B-MA","name":"Maipú"},{"code":"AR-B-MC","name":"Mar Chiquita"},{"code":"AR-B-MP","name":"Marcos Paz"},{"code":"AR-B-MD","name":"Mercedes"},{"code":"AR-B-ME","name":"Merlo"},{"code":"AR-B-MT","name":"Monte"},{"code":"AR-B-MH","name":"Monte Hermoso"},{"code":"AR-B-MR","name":"Moreno"},{"code":"AR-B-MN","name":"Morón"},{"code":"AR-B-NA","name":"Navarro"},{"code":"AR-B-NE","name":"Necochea"},{"code":"AR-B-NJ","name":"Nueve de Julio"},{"code":"AR-B-OL","name":"Olavarría"},{"code":"AR-B-PA","name":"Patagones"},{"code":"AR-B-PJ","name":"Pehuajó"},{"code":"AR-B-PE","name":"Pellegrini"},{"code":"AR-B-PG","name":"Pergamino"},{"code":"AR-B-PL","name":"Pila"},{"code":"AR-B-PX","name":"Pilar"},{"code":"AR-B-PI","name":"Pinamar"},{"code":"AR-B-PU","name":"Puán"},{"code":"AR-B-QU","name":"Quilmes"},{"code":"AR-B-RM","name":"Ramallo"},{"code":"AR-B-RU","name":"Rauch"},{"code":"AR-B-RI","name":"Rivadavia"},{"code":"AR-B-RO","name":"Rojas"},{"code":"AR-B-RP","name":"Roque Pérez"},{"code":"AR-B-SD","name":"Saavedra"},{"code":"AR-B-SL","name":"Saladillo"},{"code":"AR-B-SQ","name":"Salliqueló"},{"code":"AR-B-ST","name":"Salto"},{"code":"AR-B-SG","name":"San Andrés de Giles"},{"code":"AR-B-SA","name":"San Antonio de Areco"},{"code":"AR-B-SC","name":"San Cayetano"},{"code":"AR-B-SF","name":"San Fernando Partido"},{"code":"AR-B-SI","name":"San Isidro"},{"code":"AR-B-SN","name":"San Nicolás"},{"code":"AR-B-SP","name":"San Pedro"},{"code":"AR-B-SE","name":"San Vicente"},{"code":"AR-B-SU","name":"Suipacha"},{"code":"AR-B-TD","name":"Tandil"},{"code":"AR-B-TP","name":"Tapalqué"},{"code":"AR-B-TI","name":"Tigre"},{"code":"AR-B-TO","name":"Tordillo"},{"code":"AR-B-TQ","name":"Tornquist"},{"code":"AR-B-TR","name":"Trenque Lauquen"},{"code":"AR-B-TA","name":"Tres Arroyos"},{"code":"AR-B-TL","name":"Tres Lomas"},{"code":"AR-B-TF","name":"Tres de Febrero"},{"code":"AR-B-VM","name":"Veinticinco de Mayo"},{"code":"AR-B-VL","name":"Vicente López"},{"code":"AR-B-VG","name":"Villa Gesell"},{"code":"AR-B-VI","name":"Villarino"},{"code":"AR-B-ZA","name":"Zárate"}]
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, for I have an account there. I didn't know about an API. Definitely will give it a try. Unfortunately I am not a `vba` person, so no review, sorry.

Comment: I just modifies my 2nd answer to include `Regions` without `Sub Regions`.  It returns 9298 records in under 17 seconds.  This seems comparable to `Worksheets("HierarchyTest")` but it is hard to say because your data extends 9685 but has blank rows.

Comment: Looks like a very interesting approach, thanks for sharing. Given the multitude of updates and edits: is there any "plain vanilla" summary for your code to handle multiple requests at a time? A lean overview with the essential code would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @M.S. It's all right here - https://github.com/RaymondWise/eBird_API_VBA but no, there is no multi-threaded approach and I'm not entirely sure this is a very effective way to do this, as you can see it hasn't been updated since June, but feel free to clone the repo if you'd like. Or check out the second answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP has got the web scraping very close. But there are a couple of things that need to be tweaked.

### WriteToSheet:Sub

Case in point `WriteToSheet`.  `RetrieveCountries` pass a Base 0 array to it and `CleanSource` passes a Base 1 array.  There seems to be no attempt to adjust for the differences.  It is causing the target ranges for  both `and` to be 1 row larger then the data array.  This is causing the `#N/A` in the last row of both the `MinorSheet` and the `MajorSheet`.

The cells should also be cleared before the data in added.

Here is an easy fix:

> ```
> Set printRange = targetSheet.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(valueArray) - LBound(valueArray) + 1, 2)
> ```

This line tells me that the technique for parsing the JSON is incomplete:

> ```
> printRange.Replace What:=Chr$(34) & FIND_STRING, Replacement:=vbNullString
> ```

### RetrieveCountries:Function

Here is another attempt to jerry-rig the code because the parsing isn't quite right.

> ```
> countryArray(UBound(countryArray), 2) = Left$(countryArray(UBound(countryArray), 2), Len(countryArray(UBound(countryArray), 2)) - 2)
> ```

Adjusting the last element in an array after the value has been assigned to it, feels ... I don't know tacky??

I would probably strinp the ends of the `responseText` first.

> ```
>  responseText = Mid(responseText,4,len(responseText)-6)
> ```

---

IMO. writing a Function to process the `JSON responseText` and a Sub to merge arrays would greatly simplify the code.

> ```
> Function JSONCodeNameToArray(responseText As String)  as Variant()
>
> Sub MergeJSONArrays(Arr1 as Variant(), Arr2 As Variant())
> ```

I think that it would be even easier to pass a Dictionary with the `responseText`.  This would make adding the "Sub Regions" really simple.

> ```
> Sub AddJSON(ByRef responseText As String, ByRef Dic As Object)
> ```

---

### Addendum

### CreateHierarchy:Class

I am not going to examine this class but instead am going to show an easier way to create the hierarchy using sequel.  To simplify writing the SQL I pasted the worksheets from `ebird.xlsm` into an Access database.  I then used the query designer to write and test the sql.  The query can also be modify to ran against `ebird.xlsm`.  You will have to enclose the worksheet names followed by $ in brackets(e.g [SubNat2Sheet$] .

```
SELECT countrySheet.[Country Code], countrySheet.Country, SubNat1Sheet.[Region Code], SubNat1Sheet.[Region Name]
FROM countrySheet INNER JOIN SubNat1Sheet ON countrySheet.[Country Code] = Left(SubNat1Sheet.[Region Code],2)
UNION ALL
SELECT countrySheet.[Country Code], countrySheet.Country, SubNat2Sheet.[Region Code], SubNat2Sheet.[Region Name]
FROM countrySheet INNER JOIN SubNat2Sheet ON countrySheet.[Country Code] = Left(SubNat2Sheet.[Region Code],2)
```

[image: EBird Hierarchy Demo]

Comment: @Raystafarian Thanks.  I updated my answer to show how to create the hierarchy using sql.

Comment: @Raystafarian I went ahead signed up and got an API Key.  The `csv` format really simplifies the code. Here is my test code: [Ebird Hierarchy.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15ugcGnfGE8WhEgfwB547DsKzMcxavAfq).  I think that it will help you as you develop your project.  Thanks for sharing the API  and your code.

Comment: That's excellent of you - thanks! The next stage is pulling data again but making charts with it.

Comment: Incredible improvement - 62 seconds. Incredible.

Comment: @Raystafarian thanks.  The performance gain comes from only making a 2nd http request when needed. If you change the field data types to `adVarChar` and specify the field size (e.g. `.Append COUNTRYNAME, adVarChar, 50`), you will be able to sort the recordset.  I would `.UpdateBatch`, `.Sort` and then `.Movefirst`. Example:  `.Sort = "[" & COUNTRYNAME & "] ASC, [" & REGIONCODE & "]"`

Comment: The only thing is, despite it seeming differently, the only way a subregion can exist is if the major region exists, so it's not actually polling down to the third level.

Comment: lol...so much for the performance gain!@

Comment: Fixed it and got 776 seconds

Answer (score 1):

My first answer was a review of the OP's post.  This answer is an alternate approach.

The my first solution and OP's approach took about 775 seconds to make 3936 synchronized WinHttp.WinHttpRequest requests.  Using asynchronous MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP requests with a callback class completes the same 3936 requests to 16 seconds.

[image: Results Image]

### UpdateRegions:Sub

```
Public Sub UpdateRegions()
    Dim StartTime As Long: StartTime = Timer
    Dim Target As Range
    Dim Controller As EBirdController
    Set Controller = New EBirdController
    Controller.Initialize

    While Not Controller.ReadyStateComplete
        DoEvents
    Wend

    With Worksheets("Results")
        .Cells.Clear
        With .Range("A1").Resize(1, 6)
            .Value = Array("Contry Code", "Country", "Region Code", "Region", "Sub Region Code", "Sub Region")
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Interior.Color = 6299648
            .Font.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        End With
        Set Target = Controller.CopyToRange(.Range("A2"))

        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Target.Columns("B"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Target.Columns("D"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Target.Columns("F"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With .Sort
            .SetRange Target.Resize(Target.Rows.Count + 1).Offset(-1)
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
    MsgBox "Run Time in Seconds: " & Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
End Sub
```

### EBirdController:Class

```
Option Explicit
Private Const COUNTRY_URL As String = "https://ebird.org/ws2.0/ref/region/list/country/world.csv"
Private Const REGION_BASE_URL As String = "https://ebird.org/ws2.0/ref/region/list/subnational"
Private Const MAX_CONNECTIONS As Long = 50
Private Type Members
    CompletedRequestsList As Object
    OpenRequestsList As Object
    RequestStack As Object
End Type
Private m As Members

Private Enum DataFields
    dfCode = 1
    dfName
End Enum

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m.CompletedRequestsList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Set m.OpenRequestsList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Set m.RequestStack = CreateObject("System.Collections.Stack")
End Sub

Private Function getRequestData(Request As EBirdRegionalRequest) As String()
    Dim values() As String, results() As String
    Dim index As Long, r As Long
    values = Split(Request.getResponseText, Chr(10))

    If UBound(values) > 1 Then ReDim results(1 To UBound(values) - 1, 1 To 2) Else ReDim results(0 To 0, 1 To 2)
    For r = 1 To UBound(values) - 1
        index = InStr(values(r), ",")
        results(r, dfCode) = Left(values(r), index - 1)
        results(r, dfName) = Right(values(r), Len(values(r)) - index)
    Next

    getRequestData = results
End Function

Public Sub Initialize()
    AddRequest COUNTRY_URL
    ProcessRequestStack
End Sub

Public Sub ReadyStateChangeHandler(Request As EBirdRegionalRequest)
    Dim data() As String
    Dim index As Long, r As Long
    Dim URL As String
    m.OpenRequestsList.Remove Request.URL
    data = getRequestData(Request)

    If UBound(data) = 0 Then  'And Request.URL Like REGION_BASE_URL & "2\*"
        m.CompletedRequestsList.Add Array(Request.countryCode, Request.country, Request.regionCode, Request.region, data(r, dfCode), data(r, dfName))
    Else
        For r = 1 To UBound(data)
            If Request.URL = COUNTRY_URL Then
                URL = REGION_BASE_URL & "1/" & data(r, dfCode) & ".csv"
                AddRequest URL, data(r, dfCode), data(r, dfName)
            ElseIf Request.URL Like REGION_BASE_URL & "1/*" Then
                URL = REGION_BASE_URL & "2/" & data(r, dfCode) & ".csv"
                AddRequest URL, Request.countryCode, Request.country, data(r, dfCode), data(r, dfName)
            Else
                m.CompletedRequestsList.Add Array(Request.countryCode, Request.country, Request.regionCode, Request.region, data(r, dfCode), data(r, dfName))
            End If
        Next
    End If
    Set Request = Nothing
    ProcessRequestStack
End Sub

Private Sub AddRequest(URL As String, Optional countryCode As String, Optional country As String, Optional regionCode As String, Optional region As String)
    Dim Request As New EBirdRegionalRequest
    With Request
        .URL = URL
        .countryCode = countryCode
        .country = country
        .regionCode = regionCode
        .region = region
    End With
    m.RequestStack.Push Request
End Sub

Private Sub ProcessRequestStack()
    Dim Request As EBirdRegionalRequest
    If m.OpenRequestsList.Count = MAX_CONNECTIONS Then Stop
    Do Until m.OpenRequestsList.Count = MAX_CONNECTIONS Or m.RequestStack.Count = 0
        Set Request = m.RequestStack.Pop
        m.OpenRequestsList.Add Request.URL
        Request.setCallback Me
    Loop
End Sub

Public Function CopyToRange(Target As Range) As Range
    Dim results() As Variant
    If m.CompletedRequestsList.Count > 0 Then
        results = m.CompletedRequestsList.ToArray
        results = Application.Transpose(results)
        results = Application.Transpose(results)
        Set Target = Target.Resize(UBound(results), UBound(results, 2))
        Target.Value = results
    End If
    Set CopyToRange = Target
End Function

Public Property Get ReadyStateComplete() As Boolean
    ReadyStateComplete = m.OpenRequestsList.Count = 0 And m.RequestStack.Count = 0
End Property
```

### EBirdRegionalRequest:Class

```
Option Explicit
Private Const API_KEY As String = "Sign up and get your own key..lol"
Private Const API_REQUEST_HEADER As String = "X-eBirdApiToken"
Private Type Members
    Controller As EBirdController
    responseText As String
    XMLHttpReq As Object
End Type
Private m As Members

Public country As String
Public countryCode As String
Public region As String
Public regionCode As String
Public subRegion As String
Public subregionCode As String
Public URL As String

Function getResponseText() As String
    getResponseText = m.XMLHttpReq.responseText
End Function

Public Sub ReadyStateChangeHandler()
Attribute ReadyStateChangeHandler.VB_UserMemId = 0
    If m.XMLHttpReq.readyState = 4 Then
        m.Controller.ReadyStateChangeHandler Me
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub setCallback(Controller As EBirdController)
    Set m.Controller = Controller
    Set m.XMLHttpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    With m.XMLHttpReq
        .onreadystatechange = Me
        .Open "GET", URL, True
        .setRequestHeader API_REQUEST_HEADER, API_KEY
        .Send
    End With
End Sub
```

### References

http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/vba_web_pages_services/#_Toc173749363
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757030.aspx
http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2006/10/09/async-xmlhttp-calls/
https://github.com/driverdan/node-XMLHttpRequest/blob/master/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js#L358
https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/

### Max Connections

There is no noticeable difference between having 50 or 100 open connections at one time.  Increasing `MAX_CONNECTIONS` to 250 causes the code not to complete.  For some reason this increases the callback time and causes a number of requests not to be returned to the `Controller`.

### Edits

I update the code to late binding.  This is no longer a need for any "External Library References".

Comment: A second answer that's faster? I will try this, thank you. I've never worked "Async" before

Comment: @Raystafarian `RegoinRS As EbirdReginalRequest` is legacy code please remove that line.   I had issues with the recordset   accepting some characters so I converted it to an array.  I update my answer.

Comment: Here is a download link: [EBird Asnc.xlsm](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JSjSRXJFY08XeLAOESMSB_f1n5Q7Hzgp).  You'll need to add your API key.

Comment: Sorry, that code is not needed ethier.  I added that to try and figure out why having too many open connections prevents the code from completing.

Comment: That was the only thing different - I wonder why my copies didn't work. Either way this is superb!

Comment: Thanks!  I can't wait for you to post the next stage.  I don't have much experience with charts.  It will be an interesting change  from the norm.

Comment: Yeah I have to read through all your references and try to understand, seems it would improve my hotspot and checklist requests

Comment: Oh, my copy didn't work because the module wasn't exported, given the attribute `onreadystatechange` and re-imported.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79181/discussion-between-tinman-and-raystafarian).

Comment: The problem with setting `MAX_CONNECTIONS` to 250 might be related to port exhaustion (most likely at a NAT, because your computer has more than enough ports).

Comment: @PeterTaylor [Frequently asked questions about ServerXMLHTTP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/290761/frequently-asked-questions-about-serverxmlhttp) states `"With MSXML 3.0, the maximum number of instances that can exist simultaneously within a single process is 5,460."`.  That being said, my system cannot handle that many.  When the max number of request is too high the time it takes for the individual request to return increases.  This seems to support your argument.

Comment: I'm going to go back and add the requests to a collection.  I would check the requests that did not make a callback.  If their`ReadyStateComplete = 4` and they have a valid `responseText`.  If this is the case, I will assume that too many callbacks were coming back at one time for the VBA to handle causing the requests not to be processed.  Otherwise, I surmise that you are correct about the port exhaustion.