# Function to return JSON-like objects using VBA collections and arrays

Tags: vba, json

My goal is to create a compact function that can create a JSON Like object from JSON string.  I want a function with a small footprint that I or anyone who wants to use it, can simply paste into a module and use.  At 61 lines of code, I am happy with its size and portability. Any feedback on ways to improve the performance or valid JSON strings that it can't parse would be appreciated.

Here is an image of a JSON object created from string data using a `ScriptControl`. Although the Locals Window displays the properties and values correctly, the object itself is extremely difficult to work with.

[image: objJSON]

This image shows an object created using `getJSONCollection`. Because it is made of VBA collections and arrays, it is very easy to work with.

[image: colJSON]

```
Option Explicit

Private Function getJSONCollection(ByVal Value As Variant, Optional ScriptEngine As Object) As Variant
    Const DELIMITER As String = "||"
    Dim col As Collection, JSON As Object, KeyNames() As String, results() As Variant
    Dim j As Long, k As Long, length As Long
    Set col = New Collection
    If ScriptEngine Is Nothing Then
        Set ScriptEngine = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
        ScriptEngine.Language = "JScript"
        ScriptEngine.AddCode "function getKeys(jsonObj) { var keys = ''; for (var n in jsonObj) { keys += n + '" & DELIMITER & "' ; } return keys.substring(0, keys.length-" & Len(DELIMITER) & "); } "
        ScriptEngine.AddCode "function isArray(jsonObj) { return ( Object.prototype.toString.call( jsonObj ) === '[object Array]' );} "
    End If

    If TypeName(Value) = "String" Then
        Set JSON = ScriptEngine.Eval("(" + Value + ")")
    ElseIf TypeName(Value) = "JScriptTypeInfo" Then
        Set JSON = Value
    End If

    KeyNames = Split(ScriptEngine.Run("getKeys", JSON), DELIMITER)

    If ScriptEngine.Run("isArray", JSON) Then
        length = CallByName(JSON, "length", VbGet)
        ReDim results(length)

        For j = 0 To length - 1
            Value = CallByName(JSON, j, VbGet)
            For k = 0 To UBound(KeyNames)
                If InStr(Value, "[object Object]") Then
                    Set results(j) = getJSONCollection(CallByName(JSON, KeyNames(k), VbGet), ScriptEngine)
                Else
                    If Not IsNull(Value) Then results(j) = Value
                End If
            Next
        Next
        col.Add results, "getArray"
    Else
        For j = 0 To UBound(KeyNames)
            On Error Resume Next
                Set Value = CallByName(JSON, KeyNames(j), VbGet)
                If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Value = CallByName(JSON, KeyNames(j), VbGet)
                End If
            On Error GoTo 0

            If TypeName(Value) = "Collection" Then
                'Do Nothing
            ElseIf InStr(Value, "[object Object]") Then
                Set Value = getJSONCollection(CallByName(JSON, KeyNames(j), VbGet), ScriptEngine)
            ElseIf TypeName(Value) = "JScriptTypeInfo" Then
                'Array Handler
                Set Value = getJSONCollection(Value, ScriptEngine)
            End If

            col.Add Value, KeyNames(j)
        Next

    End If

    Set getJSONCollection = col
End Function

Sub TestJSONCollection()
    Dim JSONExamples As Object, ExampleDoc As Object
    Set ExampleDoc = getDocument("http://json.org/example.html")
    Set JSONExamples = ExampleDoc.getElementsByTagName("Pre")
    Example1 JSONExamples(0).innerText

End Sub

Sub Example1(JSONString As String)
    Dim objJSON As Object, colJSON As Collection
    Set objJSON = DecodeJSON(JSONString)
    Set colJSON = getJSONCollection(JSONString)
    Debug.Print "Example1: JSON String"
    Debug.Print JSONString
    Debug.Print String(20, "*") & "Example1: Output" & String(20, "*")

    Debug.Print "colJSON!glossary!title:", colJSON!glossary!Title
    Debug.Print "colJSON!glossary!GlossDiv!title:", colJSON!glossary!GlossDiv!Title
    Debug.Print "colJSON!glossary!GlossDiv!GlossList!GlossEntry!ID:", colJSON!glossary!GlossDiv!GlossList!GlossEntry!ID
    Debug.Print "colJSON!glossary!GlossDiv!GlossList!GlossEntry!SortAs:", colJSON!glossary!GlossDiv!GlossList!GlossEntry!SortAs
    Debug.Print "colJSON!glossary!GlossDiv!GlossList!GlossEntry!GlossTerm:", colJSON!glossary!GlossDiv!GlossList!GlossEntry!GlossTerm
    Debug.Print "colJSON!glossary!GlossDiv!GlossList!GlossEntry!Acronym:", colJSON!glossary!GlossDiv!GlossList!GlossEntry!Acronym
    Debug.Print "colJSON!glossary!GlossDiv!GlossList!GlossEntry!Abbrev:", colJSON!glossary!GlossDiv!GlossList!GlossEntry!Abbrev
    Debug.Print "colJSON!glossary!GlossDiv!GlossList!GlossEntry!GlossDef!para:", colJSON!glossary!GlossDiv!GlossList!GlossEntry!GlossDef!para
    Debug.Print "colJSON!glossary!GlossDiv!GlossList!GlossEntry!GlossDef!GlossSeeAlso(0):", colJSON!glossary!GlossDiv!GlossList!GlossEntry!GlossDef!GlossSeeAlso!getArray()(0)
    Debug.Print "colJSON!glossary!GlossDiv!GlossList!GlossEntry!GlossDef!GlossSeeAlso(1):", colJSON!glossary!GlossDiv!GlossList!GlossEntry!GlossDef!GlossSeeAlso(1)(1), "Alt Syntax"
    Debug.Print "colJSON!glossary!GlossDiv!GlossList!GlossEntry!GlossSee:", colJSON!glossary!GlossDiv!GlossList!GlossEntry!GlossSee

End Sub

Function DecodeJSON(JSONString As String) As Object
    With CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
        .Language = "JScript"
        Set DecodeJSON = .Eval("(" + JSONString + ")")
    End With
End Function

Function getDocument(URL As String) As Object
    Dim doc As Object
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        If .readyState = 4 And .Status = 200 Then
            Set doc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
            doc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
            Set getDocument = doc
        Else
            MsgBox "URL:  " & vbCrLf & "Ready state: " & .readyState & vbCrLf & "HTTP request status: " & .Status, vbInformation, "URL Not Responding"
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

This creates a JSON Collection object from the first JSON example from [json.org/example.html](http://json.org/example.html) and outputs both the values and the method used to access the values to the Immediate Window.

Example1: JSON String

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
********************Example1: Output********************
colJSON!glossary!title:     example glossary
colJSON!glossary!GlossDiv!title:          S
colJSON!glossary!GlossDiv!GlossList!GlossEntry!ID:      SGML
colJSON!glossary!GlossDiv!GlossList!GlossEntry!SortAs:  SGML
colJSON!glossary!GlossDiv!GlossList!GlossEntry!GlossTerm:             Standard Generalized Markup Language
colJSON!glossary!GlossDiv!GlossList!GlossEntry!Acronym: SGML
colJSON!glossary!GlossDiv!GlossList!GlossEntry!Abbrev:  ISO 8879:1986
colJSON!glossary!GlossDiv!GlossList!GlossEntry!GlossDef!para:         A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.
colJSON!glossary!GlossDiv!GlossList!GlossEntry!GlossDef!GlossSeeAlso(0):            GML
colJSON!glossary!GlossDiv!GlossList!GlossEntry!GlossDef!GlossSeeAlso(1):            XML           Alt Syntax
colJSON!glossary!GlossDiv!GlossList!GlossEntry!GlossSee:              markup
```

### getJSONCollection:Function

```
Function getJSONCollection(ByVal Value As Variant, Optional ScriptEngine As Object) As Variant
    Const DELIMITER As String = "||"
    Dim col As Object, JSON As Object, KeyNames() As String, results() As Variant
    Dim j As Long, k As Long, length As Long
    Set col = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    If ScriptEngine Is Nothing Then
        Set ScriptEngine = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
        ScriptEngine.Language = "JScript"
        ScriptEngine.AddCode "function getKeys(jsonObj) { var keys = ''; for (var n in jsonObj) { keys += n + '" & DELIMITER & "' ; } return keys.substring(0, keys.length-" & Len(DELIMITER) & "); } "
        ScriptEngine.AddCode "function isArray(jsonObj) { return ( Object.prototype.toString.call( jsonObj ) === '[object Array]' );} "
    End If

    If TypeName(Value) = "String" Then
        Set JSON = ScriptEngine.Eval("(" + Value + ")")
    ElseIf TypeName(Value) = "JScriptTypeInfo" Then
        Set JSON = Value
    End If

    KeyNames = Split(ScriptEngine.Run("getKeys", JSON), DELIMITER)
    If Len(Value) = 0 Then
        'Do Nothing
    ElseIf ScriptEngine.Run("isArray", JSON) Then
        length = CallByName(JSON, "length", VbGet)
        ReDim results(length - 1)

        For j = 0 To length - 1
            Value = CallByName(JSON, j, VbGet)
            For k = 0 To UBound(KeyNames)
                If InStr(Value, "[object Object]") Then
                    Set results(j) = getJSONCollection(CallByName(JSON, KeyNames(k), VbGet), ScriptEngine)
                Else
                    If Not IsNull(Value) Then results(j) = Value
                End If
            Next
        Next
        col.Add "getArray", results
    Else
        For j = 0 To UBound(KeyNames)
            On Error Resume Next
            Set Value = CallByName(JSON, KeyNames(j), VbGet)
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                Err.Clear
                Value = CallByName(JSON, KeyNames(j), VbGet)
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
            'Extract Array from Dictionary
            If TypeName(Value) = "Dictionary" Then
                If Value.Exists("getArray") Then Value = Value("getArray")
            ElseIf TypeName(Value) = "Collection" Then
                'Do Nothing
            ElseIf InStr(Value, "[object Object]") Then
                Set Value = getJSONCollection(CallByName(JSON, KeyNames(j), VbGet), ScriptEngine)
            ElseIf TypeName(Value) = "JScriptTypeInfo" Then
                'Array Handler
                Set Value = getJSONCollection(Value, ScriptEngine)
            End If
            col.Add KeyNames(j), Value
        Next

    End If

    Set getJSONCollection = col
End Function
```

Comment: Am I reading this right - it's heavily recursive?

Comment: Yes, The recursion is necessary handle nested JSON objects.  I actually wrote this after I started a review on your question [Retrieve data from eBird API and create multi-level hierarchy of locations](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/196453/retrieve-data-from-ebird-api-and-create-multi-level-hierarchy-of-locations).

Comment: It works very well on selecting all the child nodes ... however I gave it a query with 50 rows and it populated all 50 records in the collection with the same values from one row.. so I had 50 rows but all had the same record details

Comment: @StephenLaurence Thanks.  I'll check it out.

Comment: @TinMan Have you resolved Stephen's concern? It would be nice to list the dependencies: I get a compile error on `Set doc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument`.

Comment: @TravisBemrose I don't remember.  I think that the MSScriptControl.ScriptControl is no longer supported.