# Data scraping from Internet with Excel-VBA

Tags: vba, excel, data-mining

I have built an Excel application, which gets all the titles of books from Amazon.com, which it is asked to do and scrapes the following data out of them:

- Book Title
- Author
- Price

**What do you need to run the app?**

3 worksheets in Excel, named as in the picture:

[image]

Then in `tblInput`, make sure to write some keywords in range `A2:A4` and execute the `Main` function. No dependencies or additional Excel libraries to be added.

The code is also in [GitHub here](https://github.com/Vitosh/VBA_personal/tree/master/DataScrapingFromInternet). I wrote a blog post about it - http://www.vitoshacademy.com/vba-data-scraping-from-internet-with-excel-part-2/

**AmazonInternet**

```
Public Function PageWithResultsExists(appIE As Object, keyword As String) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo PageWithResultsExists_Error

    Dim allData As Object
    Set allData = appIE.document.getElementById("s-results-list-atf")
    PageWithResultsExists = True
    IeErrors = 0

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

PageWithResultsExists_Error:

    WaitSomeMilliseconds
    IeErrors = IeErrors + 1

    Select Case Err.Number

        Case 424

            If IeErrors > MAX_IE_ERRORS Then
                PageWithResultsExists = False
                IeErrors = 0
            Else
                LogMe "PageWithResultsExists", IeErrors, keyword, IeErrors
                PageWithResultsExists appIE, keyword
            End If
        Case Else
            Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End Select

End Function

Public Function MakeUrl(i As Long, keyword As String) As String

    MakeUrl = "https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_" & i & "?rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3A" & keyword & "&page=" & i & "&keywords=" & keyword

End Function

Public Sub Navigate(i As Long, appIE As Object, keyword As String)

    Do While appIE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop

    With appIE
        .Navigate MakeUrl(i, keyword)
        .Visible = False
    End With

    Do While appIE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop

End Sub
```

**ConstValues**

```
Public IeErrors As Long
Public Const MAX_IE_ERRORS = 10
Public Const IN_PRODUCTION = False
```

**ExcelRelated**

```
Public Function GetNextKeyWord() As String

    With tblInput
        Dim lastRowB As Long
        lastRowB = lastRow(.Name, 2) + 1
        GetNextKeyWord = Trim(.Cells(lastRowB, 1))
        If Len(GetNextKeyWord) <> 0 Then .Cells(lastRowB, 2) = Now
    End With

End Function

Public Sub WriteFormulas()

    Dim i As Long
    With tblInput
        For i = lastRow(.Name) To 2 Step -1
            .Cells(i, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(Summary!C[1],Input!RC[-2])"

            .Cells(i, 4).FormulaArray = "=MAX(IF(Summary!C=RC[-3],Summary!C[-1]))"
            FormatUSD .Cells(i, 4)

            .Cells(i, 5).FormulaArray = "=AVERAGE(IF(Summary!C[-1]=Input!RC[-4],Summary!C[-2]))"
            FormatUSD .Cells(i, 5)
        Next i
    End With

End Sub

Public Sub FixWorksheets()
    OnStart
    With tblInput
        .Range("B1") = "Start Time"
        .Range("C1") = "Count"
        .Range("D1") = "Max"
        .Range("E1") = "Average"
    End With

    With tblSummary
        .Range("A1") = "Title"
        .Range("B1") = "Author"
        .Range("C1") = "Price"
        .Range("D1") = "Keyword"
    End With

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Columns.AutoFit
    Next ws
    OnEnd
End Sub

Public Sub FormatUSD(myRange As Range)

    myRange.NumberFormat = "_-[$$-409]* #,##0.00_ ;_-[$$-409]* -#,##0.00 ;_-[$$-409]* ""-""??_ ;_-@_ "

End Sub


Public Sub CleanWorksheets()

    tblRawData.Cells.Delete
    tblSummary.Cells.Delete
    tblInput.Columns("B:F").Delete

End Sub

Public Function GetNthString(n As Long, myRange As Range) As String

    Dim i As Long
    Dim myVar As Variant

    myVar = Split(myRange, vbCrLf)
    For i = LBound(myVar) To UBound(myVar)
        If Len(myVar(i)) > 0 And n = 0 Then
            GetNthString = myVar(i)
            Exit Function
        ElseIf Len(myVar(i)) > 0 Then
            n = n - 1
        End If
    Next i

End Function


Public Function GetPrice(myRange As Range) As String

    Dim i As Long
    Dim myVar As Variant
    myVar = Split(myRange, "$")

    If UBound(myVar) > 0 Then
        GetPrice = Mid(myVar(1), 1, InStr(1, myVar(1), " "))
    Else
        GetPrice = ""
    End If

End Function

Public Sub WriteToExcel(appIE As Object, keyword As String)

    If IN_PRODUCTION Then On Error GoTo WriteToExcel_Error

    Dim allData As Object
    Set allData = appIE.document.getElementById("s-results-list-atf")

    Dim book As Object
    Dim myRow As Long

    For Each book In allData.getElementsByClassName("a-fixed-left-grid-inner")
        With tblRawData
            myRow = lastRow(.Name) + 1
            On Error Resume Next
            .Cells(myRow, 1) = book.innertext
            .Cells(myRow, 2) = keyword
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
    Next

    IeErrors = 0

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

WriteToExcel_Error:

    IeErrors = IeErrors + 1

    If IeErrors > MAX_IE_ERRORS Then
        Debug.Print "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure WriteToExcel, line " & Erl & "."
    Else
        LogMe "WriteToExcel", IeErrors, keyword, IeErrors
        WriteToExcel appIE, keyword
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub RawDataToStructured(keyword As String, firstRow As Long)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = firstRow To lastRow(tblRawData.Name)
        With tblRawData
            If InStr(1, .Cells(i, 1), "Sponsored ") < 1 Then
                Dim title As String
                title = GetNthString(0, .Cells(i, 1))
                Dim author As String
                author = GetNthString(1, .Cells(i, 1))
                Dim price As String
                price = GetPrice(.Cells(i, 1))
                If Not IsNumeric(price) Or price = "0" Then price = ""
                Dim currentRow As String: currentRow = lastRow(tblSummary.Name) + 1
                With tblSummary
                    .Cells(currentRow, 1) = title
                    .Cells(currentRow, 2) = author
                    .Cells(currentRow, 3) = price
                    .Cells(currentRow, 4) = keyword
                End With
            End If
        End With
    Next i

End Sub

Public Function lastRow(wsName As String, Optional columnToCheck As Long = 1) As Long

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets(wsName)
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, columnToCheck).End(xlUp).Row

End Function
```

**General**

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)

Public Sub OnEnd()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    ThisWorkbook.Date1904 = False

    Application.StatusBar = False

End Sub

Public Sub OnStart()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    ThisWorkbook.Date1904 = False

    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

End Sub

Public Sub LogMe(ParamArray arg() As Variant)

    Debug.Print Join(arg, "--")

End Sub

Public Sub PrintMeUsefulFormula()

    Dim strFormula  As String
    Dim strParenth  As String

    strParenth = """"

    strFormula = Selection.FormulaR1C1

    strFormula = Replace(strFormula, """", """""")

    strFormula = strParenth & strFormula & strParenth
    Debug.Print strFormula

End Sub

Public Sub WaitSomeMilliseconds(Optional Milliseconds As Long = 1000)
    Sleep Milliseconds
End Sub
```

**StartUp**

```
Public Sub Main()

    If IN_PRODUCTION Then On Error GoTo Main_Error

    CleanWorksheets
    Dim keyword As String: keyword = GetNextKeyWord

    While keyword <> ""

        Dim appIE As Object
        Set appIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        LogMe keyword
        Dim nextPageExists As Boolean: nextPageExists = True
        Dim i As Long: i = 1
        Dim firstRow As Long: firstRow = lastRow(tblRawData.Name) + 1

        While nextPageExists

            WaitSomeMilliseconds
            Navigate i, appIE, keyword
            nextPageExists = PageWithResultsExists(appIE, keyword)
            If nextPageExists Then WriteToExcel appIE, keyword
            i = i + 1

        Wend

        LogMe Time, keyword, "RawDataToStructured"
        RawDataToStructured keyword, firstRow
        keyword = GetNextKeyWord
        WaitSomeMilliseconds 4000
        appIE.Quit

    Wend

    FixWorksheets
    WriteFormulas

    LogMe "Program has ended!"

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

Main_Error:

    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure Main, line " & Erl & "."

End Sub
```

In general, I probably could have done it with some OOP/classes, but I have considered not to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

- `OnStart` and `OnEnd` should be called from `Main`.
- Although, I am a proponent of using single letter iterates in simple `For` loops, I think that `i` should have a more descriptive name like `pageIndex`.

  > ```
  > Navigate pageIndex, appIE, keyword
  > ```
- `Sleep` - A common subroutine used across many programming languages. 
  I see no reason to wrap it in `WaitSomeMilliseconds()`.  You could even give it a default value.

  > ```
  > Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (Optional ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr = 1000)
  > ```
- I don't see any reason to use `Sleep` in the first place.  I would use `appIE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE` instead because the only thing that you are waiting on is the Page to load.  There is no lazy loading or controls to be clicked.

  > ```
  > Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4
  > While appIE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
  > ```
- `PageWithResultsExists()` - Probably the biggest reason for the slow code.  The way the code is structured it runs until a page is called that has no data and checks that page for 10 seconds.  The last link in the Paginator class name is `pagnDisabled`.  You can get the last page number by checking its `innerText`.
- `WriteToExcel()` - Why?  This just adds an extra layer of complexity and slows down the code.  Simply process the data in memory.
- `MakeURL()` - I know getters are pretty boring but I would still use `getURL()`.  No big deal though.
- `WriteFormulas()` - You should write all the formulas at once after all the data is processed.
- `GetPrice()` - There is no distinction made between Paperback, Hardcover or Kindle.  I would expand the dataset to include all the categories; so that you are not comparing apples to oranges.
- Microsoft HTML Object Library - This library is very convenient when working with HTML.  Since there is only one version of the library, I would take advantage of early binding and intellisense by setting a reference to it.

[image: Microsoft HTML Object Library]

I only use Internet Explorer which I need to process events, I prefer `XMLHTTP`.

### Sample Userform

The Userform should have a single Textbox with multiline set to true.  When ran the code parses 20 pages of results asynchronously in under 12 seconds.  The code is unrefined. It is just a proof of concept.

```
Option Explicit
Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim t As Double: t = Timer
    TextBox1.Text = Join(getBooks("VBA").ToArray, vbNewLine)
    Debug.Print Round(Timer - t, 2)
End Sub

Function getDocument(URL As String) As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim document As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        'open(bstrMethod As String, bstrUrl As String, [varAsync], [bstrUser], [bstrPassword])
        .Open bstrMethod:="GET", bstrUrl:=URL, varAsync:=False
        .send
        If .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE And .Status = 200 Then
            Set document = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
            document.body.innerHTML = .responseText
            Set getDocument = document
        Else
            MsgBox "URL:  " & vbCrLf & "Ready state: " & .readyState & vbCrLf & "HTTP request status: " & .Status, vbInformation, "URL Not Responding"
        End If
    End With
End Function

Function getBooks(keyword As String) As Object
    Dim server As Object, servers As Object
    Dim document As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, documents As Object
    Set servers = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Set documents = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    Dim URL As String
    URL = MakeUrl(1, keyword)

    Set document = getDocument(URL)

    documents.Add document

    Dim pageindex As Long
    For pageindex = 2 To getPageCount(document)
        URL = MakeUrl(pageindex, keyword)
        Set server = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        server.Open bstrMethod:="GET", bstrUrl:=URL, varAsync:=True
        server.send
        servers.Add server
    Next

    For Each server In servers
        While server.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
        Wend

        If server.Status = 200 Then
            Set document = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
            document.body.innerHTML = server.responseText
            documents.Add document
        End If

    Next

    Dim books As Object
    Set books = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    Dim ul As HTMLUListElement
    Dim li As HTMLLIElement

    For Each document In documents
        Set ul = document.getElementById("s-results-list-atf")

        If Not ul Is Nothing Then
            For Each li In ul.getElementsByTagName("LI")
                books.Add li.innerText
            Next
        End If
    Next

    Set getBooks = books
End Function

Function getPageCount(document As HTMLDocument) As Long
    Dim element As HTMLGenericElement
    Set element = document.querySelector(".pagnDisabled")
    If Not element Is Nothing Then getPageCount = CInt(element.innerText)
End Function

Public Function MakeUrl(i As Long, keyword As String) As String
    MakeUrl = "https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_" & i & "?rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3A" & keyword & "&page=" & i & "&keywords=" & keyword
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! :) The library is a good idea indeed, I was trying to make the code portable through copy and paste, thus I was not using early binding. On your code I get an error here `.Open bstrMethod:="GET", bstrUrl:=URL, varAsync:=False` - "448 - named arbugment is not found". I call it like this - `Debug.Print Join(getBooks("VBA").ToArray, vbNewLine)`

Comment: @Vityata I got that error using a different version of the library.  `CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")` gave me the error but `CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")` worked.  [download amazon-scraper.xlsb](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iLe2N7IxX7EkJ2IH-bzVfc-AGv1hajj5)

Comment: I have just tried the `amazon-scraper.xlsb` and still got the same error on the same place. Currently with Excel 2010, 64 bits.

Comment: @Vityata very strange.  Try removing the parameter names.

Comment: I am impressed by your remote-debugging skills! It worked! :)

Comment: Not sure if I follow this part "When ran the code parses 20 pages of results asynchronously in under 12 seconds". Where/how is the code running async?

Comment: @RyanWildry Although VBA is runs synchronously it does not have to wait on the `XMLHTTP` responses.  By setting the `XMLHTTP.Send `varAsync` parameter to True, you can have multiple connections running simultaneously. 
 You don't have to wait for each connection to return its response before opening a new connection.  My sample code is pretty crude.  A better example with more dramatic results is my answer to:   [Retrieve data from eBird API and create multi-level hierarchy of locations](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/196922/171419)

Comment: I was confused as I didn't see a callback, I guess this part: `While server.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE:DoEvents:Wend` is doing that. That's not really idiomatic IMO of async code, but, I guess it works.

Comment: @RyanWildry I agree.   I could think of a better way to explain it.

Comment: I think this line:  Set element = document.querySelector(".pagnDisabled")  needs tweaking. It will throw a 424 if not present  (unless I am missing where it is handled - which is entirely possible). Either handle the potential error or use a test  of Set element = document.querySelectorAll(".pagnDisabled") then test if element.length = 0  . You can also remove a loop by using querySelectorAll("#s-results-list-atf li"). Used typed functions where possible and add in the ByVal/ByRefs.

Comment: If there are no elements containing the class javascript returns null ans  VBA sets the object to nothing.  Testing whether or not the `element is Nothing`, which I do, should be sufficient.

Comment: I had an issue with `querySelectorAll` not being supported prior IE9 (I think??).  Inserting  `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE9 />` into the response text head tag, prior to creating the HTMLFile, should fix it.