# How to speed up the VBA scraping process

Tags: beginner, vba, excel, time-limit-exceeded, web-scraping

I want to scrape 25000 addresses using Column A cell values as search strings. I'm using the following code, it is working fine but it's too slow to extract 25000 results. Is there any way to speed up the process, like opening multiple addresses at once or something else? I'm pretty new to VBA coding. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub pullAddresses()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    
    
    
    For introw = 2 To 10
        searchstring = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & introw).Value
        IE.navigate ("https://www.google.com/search?q=" & searchstring)
        
        Do Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
        Loop
        
        
        Set ht = IE.document
        
        ''Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
        
        a = ht.getElementsByClassName("desktop-title-content")(0).innerText
        b = ht.getElementsByClassName("desktop-title-subcontent")(0).innerText
        
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & introw).Value = a & ", " & b
    
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Since you don't need to interact with the web page - click on things, scroll etc. you don't need to load a full web browser just to grab the html content. A much faster method would be to use `"MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP"` to query the page - e.g. as I have done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41717235/6609896). Note for multiple requests it's better not to create a whole new serverXMLHTTP object each time (as I'm doing there) and you should just reuse the same one like you are doing in your question for `IE`

Comment: @Greedo Why don't you make the comment into a full answer.

Comment: Remember that even if your code loops through 25,000 rows and executes in milliseconds, you're still at the mercy of the internet and Google's servers if you're executing a search there. I'd be willing to wager that if you put some timers in your code, the _vast_ majority of your execution time will be in the `Do Until...Loop` line of code. Unfortunately, you cannot parallelize the operation, since VBA doesn't support threading, either.

Comment: Your best bet is to make asynchronous MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP requests.  Check out [Retrieve data from eBird API and create multi-level hierarchy of locations](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/196922/171419).  In my answer create a list of 50 servers.  The code loop over the list checking the ready state of each server request.  When a request was ready, the result would be processed and the server would be assigned a new request. This approach was 48 times faster then using a single synchronous request.